# Current request is not a multipart request

Tags: javascript, java, html

I'm trying to send an image to my server. I'm keep getting the error: Current request is not a multipart request. When i test it in Postman it works fine.

This is my html form:

```js
function saveImageToProduct() {
    var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("#newImagesForm"));
    var encData = new URLSearchParams(formData.entries());

    fetch("/uploadFile", { method: 'POST', body: encData })
        .then(response => Promise.all([response.status, response.json()]))
        .then(function([status, myJson]) {
            if (status == 200) {
                console.log("succeed!");
            } else {
                console.log("failed!");
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error.message));

    return false;
}
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate" id="newImagesForm" method="post">
 <div>
  <p>Selecteer een afbeelding:</p>
  <input id="file" name="file" type="file"/>
 </div>
 <br>

 <div>
  <button id="button" onclick="return saveImageToProduct()" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block">
   <span>Voeg aanbieding toe</span>
  </button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Backend Java code:

```
@PostMapping("/uploadFile")
public ProductImage uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    String fileName = fileStorageService.storeFile(file);
    String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
            .path("/uploads/")
            .path(fileName)
            .toUriString();
    return new ProductImage(fileName, fileDownloadUri,
            file.getContentType(), file.getSize());
}
```

When i try to send the image i'm getting a 500 error in the backend:

```
2019-03-10 19:40:33.588 ERROR 5668 --- [io-9001-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request] with root cause org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
```

When i do it in Postman it works fine like the following image shows:

[image: Postman Working]

Any idea what i'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, it keeps saying that message and when I test on Postman it works fine. I checked the FormData content and it is Ok. What did you do to fix it? Specially on the Spring Boot code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should do the job:
You basically create a new Form object and append the file data to it.
You are able to add multiple data attributes to it by adding more "data.append" lines.

```js
    function uploadPicture() {
        var input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')
        console.log(productID);
        var data = new FormData()
        data.append('file', input.files[0])
        fetch('/uploadFile/', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
        })
        .then(response => Promise.all([response.status, response.json()]))
        .then(function([status, myJson]) {
            if (status == 200) {
                console.log("succeed!");
            } else {
                console.log("failed!");
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
    }
```

HTML:

```html
        <input type="file" name="file" id="fileinput">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="uploadPicture()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try modifying it -

```
var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("#newImagesForm")[0]);
```